# Высокая нагрузка на Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, производительность

На предприятии сделал справочник телефонный на yii2 и angularjs. Народу до 100 человек. Работает быстро, всем нравится. Тут решил потестить и залить 50000 пользователей. Результат - страница грузится минуту и потом жутко тормозит. Снизил до 5000 - чуть лучше но тоже не идеал. Вообщем пока считаю, что справочнику оптимально не более 1000 записей. 
**Вопрос в следующем - angular вообще для такого годится?**

Вывожу записи вот так

```
<div ng-repeat="m in totalmans = (item.mans| filter:search)">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">
        <div><span ng-cloak ng-bind="m.name"></span>&nbsp;<span ng-cloak ng-bind="m.surname"></span></div>
        <div><span ng-bind="m.phone"></span></div>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <span ng-bind="m.email"> </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Где search

```
<input ng-model="search" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Именя, фамилию или номер">
```

Список такого типа

```
    {
"id":"2",
"name":"_administraciya_",
"description":"Администрация",
"mans":[
{
"name":"Всеволод",
"surname":"Кравчук",
"phone":"102",
"email":"skyq@skyq.ru",
"dep_id":"2"
},
{
"name":"Захар",
"surname":"Любимцев",
"phone":"115",
"email":"skyq@skyq.ru",
"dep_id":"2"
}]
},
{
"id":"2",
"name":"_administraciya2_",
"description":"Администрация2",
"mans":[
{
"name":"Всеволод1",
"surname":"Кравчук1",
"phone":"102",
"dep_id":"2"
},
{
"name":"Захар",
"surname":"Любимцев",
"phone":"115",
"dep_id":"2"
}]
}
```

[phones.skyq.ru](http://phones.skyq.ru)

Comment: ты еще сами строки приведи. Вообще выводить сразу 50000 нет нужды, обычно разбивают на страницы.

Comment: А поиск тогда как организовать по всей таблице силами ангуляра?

Comment: В поиске ничего не поменяется, у тебя же нет таблицы, у тебя есть массив, который фильтруется.

Comment: Допустим. А как выводить с пагинацией?

Comment: определяешь на какой странице ты сейчас находишься, и выбираешь из отфильтрованной коллекции кусок только для текущей страницы

Comment: На простом списке все ясно. а у меня 10 департаментов и в них вложены тысячи сотрудников. Я пока не до конца вкуриваю как их разбить да еще и фильтрануть потомю.

Comment: сейчас ты только _item.mans_ используешь. Почему что-то должно поменяться?

Comment: В примере что я нашел для пагинации http://plnkr.co/edit/6PFCPuFrN6lfGHjHVwGf?p=preview фильтруется  $scope.todos.slice(begin, end). А у меня тогда как если разбивать надо массив в массиве?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51984/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Стоит делать пагинацию или бесконечный скролл. Выводить 50000 сразу на страницу нельзя, потому что из-за большого количества вотчеров страница начинает есть много ОЗУ.

Comment: наблюдателей можно и убрать.

Comment: @Grundy а какой смысл использования Ангулара, если контент будет статичным?

Comment: Например быстрое получение и отображение. Фильтрация на клиенте. Плюс куча возможностей которые в данном вопросе не рассматриваются, тот же роутинг

Comment: Быстро получить и отобразить можно и на Vanilla JS. Не вижу смысла для таких задач подключать Фреймворк.

Comment: на пустом JS - можно что угодно сделать. Получается фреймворки вообще не нужны?

Comment: @Grundy фреймворки нужны тогда, когда собственное решение приближается к размеру фреймворка. Какой смысл писать собственный велосипед, если можно использовать готовое отличное решение? Однако я считаю неверным ради маленькой задачки, которую можно быстрей решить на нативном JS, подключать тяжелый фрейморк.

Comment: Так как здесь видна только часть задачи, нельзя сказать что именно не вошло в вопрос. Следовательно нельзя оценить _всю_ задачу, поэтому нельзя сказать что она маленькая, и для нее не нужен фреймворк. Иначе любую большую задачу можно разбить на мелкие, и в итоге получится что фреймворки действительно никакие не нужны.

Comment: @Grundy вот именно, если вы не видите всю задачу, то как вы можете судить о том, что вотчеры можно убрать? =)

Comment: Потому что это табличка для вывода, а не для изменения, это раз, наблюдателей всегда можно убрать, заменив на свои компоненты/директивы